# Magento composer The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)

Tags: magento2, composer

I am executing composer install but getting below error

```
# composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
The following exception may be caused by a stale entry in your cmd.exe AutoRun
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-windows- for details


  [UnexpectedValueException]
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/var/www/html/magento/zipextensions,/var/www/html/magento/zipextensions): T
  he system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: Where are you in your directory ?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurred only of PHP-ZIP extension please enable it then issue will be solved.

**Required PHP extensions:**

- PDO/MySQL
- mbstring
- mcrypt
- mhash
- simplexml
- curl
- gd2, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both
- soap

Comment: does not work already have these

Comment: @Compu Scie got the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using command line installation, suggest that use Installer file of composer.

Download composer's window installer `Composer-Setup.exe` from https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows
and run the installer.
[image]

Comment: i am using composer install to install from .json configration

Comment: are you using linux or window?

Comment: if you using window,then  please try use git bash as command  line interface

Comment: Seems your cmd does not get packages path.I am not sure about it  but may be

Comment: im on windows, tried git bash still not working :((